# How to find all the tags matching two values using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the values in the `span class="last value"` sections, however, sometimes the sections have a minor variation, `span class="last value empty"`, and my code skips the variations, I would like to get all the sections that start with `"last value"` in the `span class="last value"`, or in alternative all the sections that are either `"last value"` or `"last value empty"`

This is the point where I am stuck:

```
    r = requests.get(baseurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    elem = soup.find_all('span', {'class':"last value"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that they are treated as two separate classes `last` and `value`. You can use a css selector like this

```
soup.select('span.last.value')
```

Example

```
html="""
<span class="last value">
1
</span>
<span class="last value empty">
2
</span>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
print(soup.select('span.last.value'))
```

Output

```
[<span class="last value">
1
</span>, <span class="last value empty">
2
</span>]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS selectors like:

```
soup.select("span[class*=lastvalue]")
```

or you can use the `scrapy selector` with xpath support:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
sel = Selector(text=r.content)
elem = sel.xpath('//span[contains(@class, "lastvalue")]')
```

Comment: Unfortunately the first returns "ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector ", while the other gives me the AttributeError: text, because later I try to convert it to text

Comment: I managed to get your solution work as well after a little tweak for the space between last and value